# cannot capture coap packets using rawcap

Tags: wireshark, coap

I have a simple coap client and coap server, implementing based on californium library. I tried to send request from coap client to coap server and request was successfully received at the server. I used also rawcap to capture my traffic because I run everything under localhost, but unfortunatelly I can not capture any coap traffic while if I send http request, it can capture http traffic. 
Therefore I would like to ask that is it possible to capture coap traffic running under localhost?

Thank you very much
Son